# PostGIS 2.3 to PostGIS 3 upgrade blocked by changes in ST_Buffer

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.3, postgis-3.0

I'm on a PostgreSQL 10.21 AWS RDS with PostGIS 2.3.7. I need to upgrade PostGIS to PostGIS 3 in order to upgrade PostgreSQL because PostgreSQL 10 is approaching EOL.

When I run `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;` I get the following output

```
WARNING:  unpackaging raster
WARNING:  PostGIS Raster functionality has been unpackaged
HINT:  type `SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade();` to finish the upgrade. After upgrading, if you want to drop raster, run: DROP EXTENSION postgis_raster;
ERROR:  cannot drop function st_buffer(geometry,double precision) because other objects depend on it
[and so on...]
```

From the [PostGIS 3 ST_Buffer()](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.0/ST_Buffer.html) documentation it seems the signature with 2 arguments has been deprecated, even though the 3rd arguments are optional/have defaults.

**So should I change every `* VIEW` that uses `ST_Buffer` to be something like `ST_Buffer(geom, radius, 8)` or `ST_Buffer(geom, radius, '')`?**

Comment: Yes, _if_ you are certain it's only those *Views* - PG doesn't check dependencies for much else than relational objects, but it is possible that the actual extension update procedures cause these (and possibly other) issues. Looping over `pg_views` and executing the `definition` text dynamically (`DO` block, with `EXECUTE` and regex altered calls to `ST_Buffer`) helps with _lots_ of *Views* - in case you don't have those DDLs handy.